# php preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to use preg_replace, remove all the links with `class="country"` and remain the links' text.

`<a href="XXXXXX" class="country">TEXT</a>` => TEXT

How to modify the `preg_replace` below?

```
$str = <<<EOT
Long long ago, there was a poor boy named <a href="index1.html">John</a>. Who was living in <a href="index2.html">Liverpoor</a>, a city of <a href="index3.html" class="country">england</a>.
EOT;
$result= preg_replace('/<a(.*?)class="country"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i','$3',$str);
echo $result;
// I want get the result as: "Long long ago, there was a poor boy named <a href="index1.html">John</a>. Who was living in <a href="index2.html">Liverpoor</a>, a city of england"
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting what you want. 'england' is the only link text that should be removed.

Comment: @Nik, no, my code broken all the links. and I still want to remain other links, just broken links which `class="country"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with most cases:

```
$result= preg_replace('/<a [^>]*class="country"[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/i','$1',$str);
```

but please consider using DOM parser instead